# How to connect textEdit widget to a function through key press event PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I want to save the text in a textEdit widget whenever the user presses Return or Enter inside the widget. But I'm not sure how to register that the user has pressed a specific key *inside* the bounds of the widget.

.returnPressed only works for lineEdits. I have tried to utilize keyPressEvent() but, as far as I can tell, that is a standalone function and I wouldn't know how to connect it to the text widget.

If I was using Tkinter, I'd write something like this:

```
entry.bind("<Return>", entry_get)
```

But I don't know how to do it in PyQt5.

Comment: Using [`keyPressEvent`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#keyPressEvent) is usually the proper choice, can you show us how you tried to use it with a [mre]? Also, do some research on the function here on StackOverflow, you'll see dozens of related questions.

Comment: A text-edit is a **multi-line** editor. How would the user add a new line if return/enter is used to trigger a save? Maybe a [keyboard shortcut](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qshortcut.html) would be a better solution?

Comment: @ekhumoro the text moves to the next line once you reach the end of the text box, it's like a text box in word

Comment: @musicamante I did research before posting this. None of it was helpful, as I could only find posts about returnPressed and implementing keyPressEvent to react to a key press in general, not within a certain widget. I copied some of that code and tried to make it work, but it gave me such a strong impression of being the wrong approach that I stopped. I thought that, since this seems like it should be a very simple thing to do, someone could give me a quick answer. If you know please just tell me, otherwise I'll skip it because I'm already overwhelmed with the rest.

Comment: @temp54 No, it doesn't. To add a new blank line, return/enter must be pressed, just like any other multi-line editor.

Comment: @ekhumoro Dude, I'm not trying to mess with you, I'm just telling you what the program is doing. I don't care if it adds and actual newline. The text moves to the next line just fine.

Comment: @temp54 `keyPressEvent` *does* react to a certain widget (the one that has keyboard focus and receives it), the important aspect is that events can also be *propagated*. There are basically two main approaches to achieve what you want, but depending on how you're creating your program, their implementation might be *very* different. So, please, even if it doesn't work or it seems "wrong", provide a [mre] based on your code, so that we can give you more appropriate answers.

Comment: @temp54 Moving to the next line just scrolls the view. It has nothing to do with adding blank lines.

Comment: @ekhumoro I never said anything about blank lines

Answer (score 2):

Only override keyPressEvent:

```py
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QTextEdit


class TextEdit(QTextEdit):
    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        super().keyPressEvent(event)
        if event.key() in (Qt.Key_Enter, Qt.Key_Return):
            print("save")


def main():
    app = QApplication([])

    w = TextEdit()
    w.show()

    app.exec_()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The same logic can be applied with an event filter. Using QShorcut is not an option as it consumes the event preventing QTextEdit from adding lines.

Comment: @temp54 please review the [tour]